# how to yank a code block without folded content?

Tags: vim, fold, yank

I write a blog that describe the fold of vim. So I need the code like this.

```
+-- 15 lines: set_up_socket_dir () {--------------------------------------------
```

But when I yank the line, actually yank the folded code.  how can i get that line  from vim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To render the buffer / a range as you see it in Vim (including syntax highlighting and folding), you can use the built-in `:TOhtml` command. This gets you HTML. For the entire window layout, there's the [ScreenShot plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1552).

If you just want the plain text, I would launch console Vim, select the entire contents with the mouse, and use your terminal's copy functionality to copy the selection to the system's clipboard. (I believe you can also do this with *screen* or *tmux*.)

Answer (score 5):

there is a vim function you may want to check out:

```
:h foldclosed(
```

you could write a `:g` command line with this function:

```
:g/^/if line('.')==foldclosed('.') || foldclosed('.')==-1|y Z |endif
```

So your workflow would be:

`qzq`  to clear register `z`

`...visual select lines...`

`'<,'>g/^/if line('.')==foldclosed('.') || foldclosed('.')==-1|y Z |endif`

`"zp` do paste

you could create a mapping or command if you use it often.

it works like:

[image]

Comment: Excellent.  I found that the same technique, using `foldlevel` was useful in my case.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you want to copy the closed fold text heading . You can do this with modeless selection (see `:help modeless-selection`). Mark the text with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> depressed.

Comment: Have been looking for this, did know how to mark but not how to copy it, (when GUI). It's not easy to know what to do `:help` on.

Comment: @244an: On Unix systems (including OSX) marking _is_ copying, not sure if it works on Windows though.

Comment: I know, but on Windows it's trickier, you have to enter command mode and do `<C-Y>` - if for some reason you don't copy it the usual way.

Comment: On Windows (or other systems, really) you can just do `:set guioptions+=A` to make it copy as you select with a modeless selection.